# How to change dmenu's font size in xmonad?

Tags: fonts, xmonad, dmenu

I just start to use xmonad window manager. It is wonderful. I tried to modify some configurations to get it work more suitable for me.

My question is:

1. How to make a keyboard shortcut for commonly used apps? For example, I'd like to bind `Chrome` to `mod-b`.
2. How to change the `dmenu` font? I tried to add options to the exec part:

   ```
   dmenu_run -fn "-xos4-terminus-medium-r-*-*-14-*"
   dmenu_run -fn 'Droid Sans Mono-14'
   ```

but it doesn't work.

---

**Edit**:

Question 1 solved by:

> In the section `myKeys conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modm}) = M.fromList $`
>
> add:
>
> ```
> -- launch Chrome browser
> , ((modm, xK_b), spawn "exe=`google-chrome`")
> ```

---

**Edit 2**:

Question 2 solved by https://askubuntu.com/questions/326907/custom-font-with-dmenu

Comment: Do you have this fonts installed in your system? Also, for Droid font you need package `dmenu-xft`.

Comment: @kirill-a Thank you! Yes. I have both fonts installed. Where could I find the `dmenu-xft`?

Answer (score 1):

You must use the X Logical Font Description ("XLFD") full name for the font provided by `xfontsel`. The output should look something like this:

```
'-sazanami-mincho-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*'
```

which you must use in the config file:

```
dmenu -fn '-sazanami-mincho-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*'
```

`xfontsel` allows you to preview the different settings.

To use non-bitmap fonts, you need to [patch](http://blog.aaronbieber.com/blog/2013/03/12/dmenu-plus-xft-equals-awesome/) and recompile `dmenu` (see [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326907/custom-font-with-dmenu) for help) or just download already [patched version](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/dmenu-xft/). Then you'll be able to use fonts like droid-sans.

Comment: I downloaded the patched version, did a `make clean install`. When I run `dmenu_run -fn 'DejaVu Sans Mono 14'` from shell, it said: cannot load font 'DejaVu Sans Mono 14' I did have DejaVu Sans Mono font installed. May I ask what's wront?

Comment: It seems the patched version doesn't work. I patched it again and build it with the help from `http://askubuntu.com/questions/326907/custom-font-with-dmenu` Finally it works. Thank you.

Comment: Added your link to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Now days in last versions of dmenu you can just use a font name without the need to generate the XLFD name anymore.

The font name can be found with help of `fc-match --sort` command for example.

That's my config of `dmenu_run` which sets the font to be `Fira Code`, font size of 10 and the colors to look nicely with `Darcula` theme:

```bsh
dmenu_run -fn "Fira Code:size=10" -p "➜ " -nb "#282a36" -nf "#c3c3c0" -sb "#282a36" -sf "#50fa7b"
```

Where:

- `-fn` stands for font name and can be set both with or without `size=10`.
- `-p` is for prompt (text which will be printed to the left of your search area)
- `-nb` is for background color
- `-nf` is for font color
- `-sb` is for active selection color
- `-sf` is for active selection font color